# A website won’t open, opens on iPhone over the same network

Tags: networking, connection

I've suddenly lost complete access to a particular website. Every browser on both of my machines (a Windows laptop and an iMac running OS X) display a ‘Cannot connect/No server found’ error.

Meanwhile, [Down For Everyone Or Just Me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) says that the website is up and that it's just me; on top of this, it opens fine in Mobile Safari on an iPhone that is connected to the same WiFi network.

I've tried rebooting the machines and restarting the router, but nothing has fixed the problem. What could possibly be the reason for this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out for transparent proxy servers in your network. These servers automatically redirect traffic through them if your system acquires IP from them.
2. Also do the same for the browsers in your system.
3. As for yout Iphone, it seems that it gets the IP directly from the router. Additionally also check out if the IP acquired by your Iphone and PC are of the same series.
4. MAC configutation in the router generally blocks a few to many clients from access to network. Be sure to check that out too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the DNS on your computer to OpenDNS 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.

If you were already using OpenDNS, change it back to your ISPs DNS servers (Google the name of your ISP and the keywords "DNS servers").

References:

- http://www.opendns.com/